# Adding Path Field to a CCK Content Type

Tags: drupal, path, cck

I am completely blanking-out.

I want a content type to have the path field, so I can alias its path from node/n to /foo.

I can't seem to remember how to do this. When I go into Content>Content Types>Edit My_Content_Type, the path field is greyed out and doesn't display when I view an instance of the content type.

I made sure paths module had the correct permissions, but no-go.

How do I get the 'path' field to show up when creating or editing a custom content type?

Comment: Turns out, if you look below, a custom module was hiding the path field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path is not a CCK field, it is it's own system, even in D7. It is used just for path aliases  so won't, usually, be displayed in a node.

As Nikit suggests, pathauto may cause the box to be grayed out. Also I suppose you should make sure the path module is turned on.

Comment: path is enabled. I can make an alias using path auto, but isn't there a way to make the path field show up in the content type's edit page, so that a user could overwrite it?

Comment: That should be a standard path feature, and looks like it has been for about 3 years. which version of drupal and pathauto are you using?

Comment: Ahh, I see. I inherited a bunch of complicated Drupal code (custom modules). It looks like the module author of the code I inherited is hiding that field. I never would have realized that unless I had gone into his module code.